# How to copy multiple column from one excel file and paste them according to user's need in another excel file using python's xlsx?

Tags: python, xlsx

I want to copy a column from an excel file and then paste it in another using python.

I have tried xlsx and read the column one by one and converted it to a list and then make a for loop over that list to write in new excel file

Note: The get_index function is reading the column from file1 and converting to a list and write_t0_col function is printing that list to new excel file but it's printing the first list in all the columns

```
def get_index(a, workbook):
    global c1
    List = []
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        c1 = sheet.cell_value(i, a)
        convert(c1, List)
    write_to_col(List, workbook)
    print(List)

def write_to_col(data, workbook):  # function to write the list into a column
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for item in data:
        for col in range(5):
            worksheet.write(row, col, item)
        row += 1
    #col+=1

    workbook.close()
```

output that i want is to print all the list into column one by one as they are called from user.

Comment: what does `convert(c1, List)` do ?

Comment: convert will convert the column data into list, the data which is extracting from file 1 and then that list is passing to function write_to_col to print in new col of new file

Comment: I have identified the problem, can anyone tell me that how do I keep my file open as i have closed the workbook after writing into the column.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to copy and paste excel columns with python, using `pandas` is enough:

```
import pandas as pd
# read excel
xl = pd.ExcelFile("originExcel.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("your sheet name")

# get the column you want to copy
column = df["your column name"]

# paste it in the new excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter('newExcel.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    column.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= "new sheet name", index = False)
```

Comment: thats a great solution but what if we want to automate this process, right now we are mentioning the column name

Comment: `df.columns` gets all column titles as a list. If you want to replace column name with index, this will work `df[df.columns[index]]`